# Filtering items in a section with dust.js based on the value of a json subelement

Tags: javascript, dust.js

Is there a way to select certain elements in a JSON view based on an sub-element's string value using Linked In's version of dust.js? For example, if I had this JSON view:

```
{
    people: [ 
        { name: "Fred", type: "a" },
        { name: "Harry", type: "a" },
        { name: "Linda", type: "a" },
        { name: "Mary", type: "b" },
        { name: "Bob", type: "b" },
        { name: "Joey", type: "b" }
    ]
}
```

and I wanted this output:

Fred

Harry

Linda

how would the template differ from this simple one?

```
{#people}
    <br/>{name}
{/people}
```

This would be executed in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but you need to include [dust helpers](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers):

```
{#people}
  {@eq key=type value="a"}
    {name}
  {/eq}
{/people}
```

A few things to note:

1. We are using the @eq helper. Don't use the @if helper, even if it is
   available (it has security and performance problems).
2. When referencing a value inside of a helper, you don't need to wrap it in `{ }`. In this example, we use `key=type`, instead of `key={type}` or `key="{type}"`.

Comment: Thank you. That would indeed work, but it would also iterate over all elements. I ended up using JSPath to get a subset of nodes with their built in comparison operators.